# C++ Return Array of Structs

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, return

Ok so I have a struct listed as such:

```
typedef struct name
{
    string thing1;
    string thing2;
    int thing3;
    int thing4;
};
```

I use a function that runs through data and assigns everything into an array of structs establish the inside struct array.
name structname;

function runs fine and assigns everything inside correctly...
`structname[i].thing1 structname[i].thing2` etc. will cout fine inside the function

My question is how do I assign the function to return this array of structs?  I can't seem to use pointers to do so and I have looked extensively on the web to find an answer.

EDIT:  First off, first post here.  always been using the resources, but i can't stress again how helpful in learning php, c++, etc. y'all have been.
I can pass structs into the function fine using a pointer, it's just returning an array of structs which seems to be the issue.  My function is set up as a void so I have been using the void function(struct name &input) but that clearly doesn't seem to modify the struct.  I have also tried to use the function as a return type but it mismatches as it is an array and not a struct.

Comment: C or C++? While the problem applies to both languages, the answers will differ greatly.

Comment: @DieterLücking: You cannot return a raw array by value in C or C++

Comment: No need to mess with C arrays - use std::vector<name> or std::array<name> (the latter if you can use C++11).

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it.

```
typedef struct name
{
    string thing1;
    string thing2;
    int thing3;
    int thing4;
};

name** getNames(size_t count) {
    size_t i;
    name** names = malloc(count * sizeof(*names));
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        names[i] = malloc(sizeof(**names));
        names[i]->thing1 = "foobar";
    }
    return names;
}
```

Edit:
I just noticed this is about c++, so the other answer is probably better.

Comment: both C and C++ are in the tags, so this answer is certainly still appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you would use std::vector:

```
std::vector<name> f(); // return by value
```

or

```
void f( std::vector<name>& v); // take by reference and assign to vector
                               // inside a function f
```

In C you cannot return array types. You can return pointers to arrays. Two options are: to allocate memory in function f or fill preallocated memory (preallocated by the caller). For example:

1.

```
name* f( int count) {
    name *ret = malloc( count * sizeof( name));
    if( !ret)
        return NULL;

    for( int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
        // ret[i] = ... initialize  

    return ret;
};

int main() {
    name *p = f(10);
    if( p) {
        // use p
        free( p);  // don't forget
    }

    return 0;
}
```

2.

```
void f( name* p, int count) {

    if( !p)
        return;

    for( int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
        // p[i] = ... initialize  
};

int main() {
    name *p = malloc( 10 * sizeof( name));
    f( p, 10);
    free( p);  // don't forget
    return 0;
}
```

3.

```
void f( struct name p[], int count) {

    if( !p)
        return;

    for( int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
        // p[i] = ... initialize  
};

int main() {
    name p[10];
    f( p, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  In C++ using the vector method, does the f() function needs a return of return name[]? Or will a return name without array brackets work?

Comment: also when passing the array<name> f(); C++ says too few arguments.

Comment: std::vector<name> f() {
 std::vector<name>v;
 v.push_back( name{"1", "2", 1, 2});
 return v;
} example: http://ideone.com/UHZd5U

Answer (score 2):

Seems this has not been mentioned. 
The reason why this approach is good as compared to creating dynamic memory inside function `func` and returning pointer to it - is that in our case, caller owns the memory (which she created and passed to function - e.g., `buff2`) and has to free it anyway. Whereas in the former case the caller might forget to free the memory returned by function. You can also use it in a way that there is no need to free anything at all (e.g., "first usage").

In C:

```
void func(struct name *x, int len)
{

   for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
   {
      // Init each array element x[i]
      x[i].thing1="text1";
      x[i].thing2="text2";
      // etc.
   }


}
```

You have to be careful to use correct `len` value otherwise you will write past the array.

Usage:

```
int main()
{
   // 1) One way - no dynamic memory
   struct name buff1[10];
   func(buff1,10);

   // 2) Other way - with dynamic memory
   struct name *buff2 = malloc(10*sizeof(struct name));
   func(buff2,10);
   free(buff2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is true, that C++ doesn't recommend return arrays, but pointers to them, but! C++ allows everything. In particular:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct h{
    int f[2];
};

h my(){
    h a;
    a.f[0]=1;
  a.f[1]=2;
return a;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    h j;
    j=my();
    cout << j.f[0];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `j` is not an array of struct, but a struct with an array inside.